# Update the index buffer each frame when rending using Metal in iOS

Tags: ios, 3d, rendering, metal

I have very dynamic data which changes each frame. The data itself is relatively small so I use

`[commandEncoder setVertexBytes:_vertices.buffer() length:_vertices.size() * sizeof(float) atIndex:0];`

to set the vertex data.

However I need to set the index data as well when drawing using:

`[commandEncoder drawIndexedPrimitives: ...];`

How can update the provided `MTLBuffer` used for the index data in `drawIndexedPrimitives` method? I need to be able to efficiently update the index buffer.

Comment: I think @warrenm's answer is the correct general purpose solution. However, lots of annoyingly dynamic geometry is just quads (particle systems, 2D graphics/fonts). In this situation, it can be useful to have a giant quad index buffer which is just [0,1,2,2,1,3  4,5,6,6,5,7] etc. This quad buffer can be reused surprisingly often and need never change.

Answer (score 4):

[This article](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/metal/synchronization/synchronizing_cpu_and_gpu_work?language=objc) contains an in-depth explanation of using multiple buffers to synchronize data between the CPU and GPU without forcing them to work in lock-step. You should read it carefully. I'll summarize the approach below.

1. Select a size for your index buffers that is large enough to hold the maximum number of indices you might need to draw.
2. Allocate a few (2-3) buffers of this size and place them in an array (of type `NSArray<id<MTLBuffer>>`). This is your reuse pool; I'll call it `indexBufferPool` below.
3. When initializing your renderer, [create a dispatch semaphore](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/dispatch/1452955-dispatch_semaphore_create?language=objc) whose value is equal to the number of buffers you put in your reuse pool. I'll call it `bufferSemaphore` below.
4. Create a buffer index member variable and initialize it to 0. I'll call it `bufferIndex` below.
5. Every time you draw, wait on the semaphore by calling `dispatch_semaphore_wait(bufferSemaphore, DISPATCH_TIME_FOREVER)`.
6. When the semaphore wait function returns, it's safe to copy new index data into the buffer at the current buffer index. Using `memcpy` or some other copying technique, copy index data into the contents of `bufferPool[bufferIndex]`.
7. Draw your primitives using `bufferPool[bufferIndex]` as the index buffer.
8. Increment `bufferIndex` by setting `bufferIndex = (bufferIndex + 1) % ResourceCount`, where `ResourceCount` is the number of buffers in the reuse pool.
9. Before committing it, add a completed handler to the current command buffer. The completed handler should call `dispatch_semaphore_signal(bufferSemaphore)`. This lets any pending calls to the draw method know that it's safe to write to the buffer at the current buffer index.

Comment: Thank you for the answer but I am aware of how triple buffering works. I was wondering if there is a recommended and effective way to update the index MTLBuffer each frame because I do not know what is the max size of the index data at the beginning. So a possible solution is to start with 3 predefined buffers with fixed size and in case I need to add more data then to allocate bigger MTLBuffers. This should work but I am wondering if this is the best way to do it

Comment: Obviously if you don't know how large the data can be, you'll need to reallocate the buffers when you exceed whatever size you chose initially. The purpose of using a reusable pool of buffers is to amortize the cost of those allocations, and the purpose of choosing a large initial size is to prevent having to reallocate at all if possible.

Comment: @warrenm is it safe to say there is no equivalent to glBufferSubdata? If the buffer cannot be modified after creation the answer should just say that. (I'm not interested in doing things the "right" way, as I'm constrained to keeping things simple during an OpenGL port.)

Comment: Certainly buffers can be modified after they're created; you can literally `memcpy` into the `contents` pointer of a buffer in shared or managed storage. That's what enables reuse of the buffers in the pool in this answer.

Comment: What you shouldn't do is modify buffer contents from the CPU when the same region of the buffer is in use by the GPU. That's why we use a pool in the first place. And we dynamically reallocate the pool buffers because the data is highly-dynamic and it's not known _a priori_ what the maximum size should be.

Comment: In modern Metal, you could also use an `MTLHeap` to suballocate lightweight, transient buffers instead of keeping an actual array of long-lived `MTLBuffer` objects. However, you still need to know how big to make the heap, so there isn't much difference in practice between using a pool of buffers and transient, heap-allocated buffers in this use case.